# How to install python2_devel on Centos8?

Tags: centos, python

Just recently started getting this message when trying to install python2_devel onto a centos8 docker image:

```
yum install python2_devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:51 ago on Wed 10 Feb 2021 01:54:39 AM UTC.
No match for argument: python2_devel
Error: Unable to find a match: python2_devel
```

I also can't install the Okey repo that it is [apparently now under](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/okey-x86_64/python2-devel-2.7.15-24.el8.x86_64.rpm.html):

```
dnf install http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/8/x86_64/release/okay-release-1-1.noarch.rpm
[root@ce6f8c08ddea /]# dnf install okay-release
Last metadata expiration check: 0:25:53 ago on Wed 10 Feb 2021 01:54:39 AM UTC.
No match for argument: okay-release
Error: Unable to find a match: okay-release
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS 8 uses `dnf` now instead of `yum`, but that is not your issue.

You are using an underscore (`_`) when you wanted to use a hyphen (`-`).

```
dnf install python2-devel
```

The release package for the `okay` repository seems to be located [here](http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/8/x86_64/release/okay-release-1-3.el8.noarch.rpm) (there is no `okay-release-1-1.noarch.rpm`, I only saw `okay-release-1-2.noarch.rpm` and `okay-release-1-3.noarch.rpm`)

Comment: Oh gosh! Silly mistake. That was driving me nuts! Thanks so much. Will delete this question!